# Which functions are continuous but nowhere Holder continuous for 0<a<1?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples, holder-spaces

Can somebody provide an example of a function that is continuous on [0,1] but **nowhere Holder continuous** with degree $\alpha$? Why is the function continuous but nowhere Holder continuous?

By nowhere Holder continuous, I mean that

$\frac{|f(x + t_n) - f(x)|}{|t_n|^\alpha} \rightarrow +\infty$ where $t_n$ is a sequence which $\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: Hi kwhy, welcome to MSE.  It would be helpful if you could provide some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for the problem, that is, something outside the problem statement itself.  For example, what examples have you tried/ruled out?  Also, I think you should have included the definition of *[Hölder continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)* in your original post, since I'd think that most don't know it off the top of their heads.

Comment: @parsiad Uniform continuity does not imply Holder continuity.

Comment: $f(x)=1/\ln x;\ f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Chilango the function was asked to be nowhere Holder continuous ; $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{\ln (x)}$ is lipschitz on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ for instance, there is only a problem at $0$

Comment: @kwhy just to be sure, could you give a formal definition of "nowhere Holder continuous"

Comment: @charMD $1/\ln x$ is Lip 1 on $[1/2,3/4]$ but not $[1/2,1].$

Comment: I have added the definition for Holder continuous

Comment: @zhw yes, of course, thank you

Comment: @kwhy thank you, but by the way you just switched the two limits ($+\infty$ and $0$)

Answer (score 7):

I'll denote $C([0,1])$ by $C.$ For $j,k,l \in \mathbb N,$ let $E_{jkl}$ denote the set of functions $f\in C$ for which there exists $a\in [0,1]$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| \le j|x-a|^{1/k}$ in the neighborhood $(a-1/l,(a+1/l) \cap [0,1].$

Claim: Each $E_{jkl}$ is closed and nowhere dense in $C.$

If the claim is proved, then because $C$ is a complete metric space, Baire shows there are functions $g\in C$ that belong to no $E_{jkl}.$ For any such $g,$ the following is true: If $\alpha> 0,$ $a\in [0,1],$ $C>0,$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $a$ relative to $[0,1],$ then

$$|g(x)- g(a)| \le C|x-a|^\alpha$$

fails to hold for some $x\in U.$ This $g$ is thus "nowhere Holder" in a very strong sense. (You never defined "nowhere Holder", btw.)

So you have the claim left to verify.